# How can I convert a chroot into a GRUB2 bootable ISO image?

Tags: grub2, chroot, livecd

Say I have a chroot containing what will be a working Linux system, and some additional init scripts to mount an overlay filesystem (e.g. AUFS) over it. I've also generated a GRUB2 boot menu.

What commands would I use to:

- Install the requisite GRUB2 binary files into $CHROOT/boot, **without modifying the host MBR**
- Generate a bootable ISO from $CHROOT, with GRUB2 as the bootloader

Note that I would rather use GRUB2 than syslinux, because syslinux does not automatically detect kernel and initrd versions.

Comment: Incase if you are experimenting with linux and want to build it from scratch, try http://linuxfromscratch.org. It has a detailed documentation about how linux can be built from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

If you have chroot there is no $CHROOT/boot, it will be just /boot.

Assuming you have already mounted `--bind` /dev /proc /dev/pts and /sys then you only need to do a `grub-install --force --no-floppy --boot-directory=/boot /dev/sdX` and assuming your boot dir is /boot and /dev/sdX the device where you want the MBR part of grub to be installed.

I'm not sure if your boot menu will be overwritten, so make a copy first.

Regarding the iso creation, [this](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) link may have a solution for you, I haven't tried, but if you are planing a live CD thingie you may need to take into account that you will be probably needing it to run the whole system from ram so you may need to create a custom initrd.